# Laravel DB mysql select where column exists in array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I send an array to my API made in Laravel 5 which is an array of allowed values ex: `[1,3,5]`

I try to do the select like this:

```
$json = (object)Input::all();

$loans = DB::table("loans")
         ->where("years", ">=", $json->year_low)
         ->where("years", "<=", $json->year_high)
         ->where("risk", $json->risks)
         ->get();
```

`risks` is the array.

What I receive from the database is and empty array.

In a test I send every possible value 0...4 but I receive an empty array.

How can I select a row which a column's value exists inside an array?

Comment: `whereIn()` perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you meant `$json->risks` is array like `[1,2,3]`, try following

```
->whereIn("risk", $json->risks)
```

[Read More](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)

Answer (score 3):

I have made some changes in your script :

```
$json = (object)Input::all();

$loans = DB::table("loans")
     ->where("years", ">=", $json->year_low)
     ->where("years", "<=", $json->year_high)
     ->whereIn("risk", array($json->risks))
     ->get();
```

This will work and you will get the array of values.